# What is the h2o dataframe GroupBy sum function doing when summing enum/categorical type columns?

Tags: h2o

Wondering about what is happening when summing columns in an h2o dataframe GroupBy object when the column types are *categorical* (specifically h2o `enum` types).

Have a pandas dataframe converted to an H2o dataframe. Am then grouping rows by a certain column and summing the other columns, eg.

```
location_id  price store
------------------
1            10    JCP
1            15    SBUX
3            20    HOL

then after grouping and summing; df.group_by('location_id').sum(['price', 'store'])

location_id  price store
------------------
1            25    <some number>
3            20    <some number>
```

Would like to know what is going on under the surface here when adding categorical column values together and can't seem to find the sum() source code for GroupBy objects in the h2o [docs](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-vajda/1/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-munging/groupby.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the h2o docs for categorical encodings (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html), for the `enum` types (which what I am using for the categorical types in my h2o dataframe) we see

> enum or Enum: Leave the dataset as is, **internally map the strings to
>   integers, and use these integers** to make splits - either via ordinal
>   nature when nbins_cats is too small to resolve all levels or via
>   bitsets that do a perfect group split. Each category is a separate
>   category; **its name (or number) is irrelevant**. For example, after the
>   strings are mapped to integers for Enum, you can split {0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5} as {0, 4, 5} and {1, 2, 3}.

So if I am interpreting this correctly (and someone please tell if if this is not correct), what is happening is that when converting the pandas frame to h2o, it is going through the different values for the columns assigned as being `enum` types and assigning an internal unique ID integer value to that label (which is used in training and predictions and such, but we normally just don't see). Thus, when doing a `df.group_by(.).sum(.)` on those `enum` columns, **we are just adding up all the internally mapped integer values for those columns** that h2o assigned when the dataframe was converted to an h2o dataframe.

Again, if this is not the most complete interpretation of what is going on here, someone please let me know.